# Edit Parser for .cs files

Tags: c#, parsing

is there a possibiliy to to edit c# code (in a file) via a parser or something? I want to add a new property /method/ interface to the class automatically. Does something already exist?

thanks,
el

Comment: It sounds like something is wrong with your architecture. I can't imagine, why one should want do to it.

Comment: So I guess that R# (and similar tools) are all wrong... ;)

Comment: i have to add an Interface and implement it on thounsands of generated classes. I dont want to do this manually. If this usecase has not been implemented already i will write my own little string parser which simply inserts a few words into a textfile (in this case a .cs file)
So there is nothing wrong with my architecture :-)

Comment: In that use case it's totaly fine to do so. I thought you would want to add properties in a pre-commit hook or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [C# grammar for the Gold Parser](http://www.devincook.com/goldparser/grammars/index.htm) (and .NET engines to process the tables), so that you may find what you need there.

Comment: thanks for your awnser but i guess this is an overkill for my needs

Comment: Well, if the pattern where you want to insert it is known in advance, a Regex-based solution may be your friend. But that is not a parser, and it does not "understand" the code it is changing, in contrast to a real parser which finally creates an AST and lets you perform consitent analysis and changes (and in the end output the final code again via CodeDom or whatever).